# @font-face loading issues in Ionic Framework Android build

Tags: android, css, angularjs, ionic-framework, font-face

I've come across a very strange problem while developing an app in Ionic Framework.

[image: Screenshot of issue]

I'm importing @font-face into my Ionic Framework application and then running the app on an Android device (Galaxy SIII). As you can see the font (Montserrat) loads everywhere except underneath the image ( and  on the initial screen). They load fine in web preview. They also load fine when using a system font ("Robot" in this case). I'm wondering if it is caused by the fonts not being preloaded for immediate use and the DOM renders before it loads the font on those particular elements.

I've set the background to red, and the red block appears, so the actual content is being delivered, but it just looks like the text is not rendering. The text is plain HTML format. But I've also injected it via an expression to see if that had any effect. It didn't. The imported font for the ionic-icons also works flawlessly.

Here is what I feel is the best hint...If i swipe the screen, voila, the text magically appears. It doesn't happen again anywhere else after this.

I'm including my CSS @font-face just in case I'm missing something...

```
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'montserratregular';
    src: url('montserrat-regular-webfont.eot#montserratregular');
    src: url('montserrat-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('montserrat-regular-webfont.woff2#montserratregular') format('woff2'),
         url('montserrat-regular-webfont.woff#montserratregular') format('woff'),
         url('montserrat-regular-webfont.ttf#montserratregular') format('truetype'),
         url('montserrat-regular-webfont.svg#montserratregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
  }

* {
      font-family: 'montserratregular', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', sans-serif!important;
      font-weight: normal !important;
  }
```

...and the corresponding HTML

```
<div ng-click="testTime()" class="fullwidth-container start-test begin" ng-if="reactionFrame === 0">
<img src="img/touch.svg" class="tap-icon">
<h1 class="test-prompt">Tap to begin</h1>
<h3>Please follow the instructions on the next screen as quickly as possible.</h3>
</div>
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening and if so, what the solution would be?

Comment: can you please post your code in github or codepen or fiddle to have a look

Comment: @Anilkumar, sorry I missed this but I ended up figuring out what is causing the problem although I'm not sure why it exactly is a problem. More in my answer below.

Comment: Hmm OK when ever it is possible for you , please upload your code in github or codepen so that I will try to figure that isssue @Jeff Callahan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of trial and error I ended up tracing the problem back to the css included in the default Ionic stylesheet. In particular these styles (by excluding this block, it fixed the problem - never isolated to just one style, though):

```
.content {
  position: relative; }

    .scroll-content {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      margin-top: -1px;
      padding-top: 1px;
      margin-bottom: -1px;
      width: auto;
      height: auto; }

    .menu .scroll-content.scroll-content-false {
      z-index: 11; }

    .scroll-view {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      overflow: hidden;
      margin-top: -1px; }
```

It seems as if the scroll state is causing the delay of the font to load. Instead of altering the Ionic.css file I disabled scroll on `<ion-content>` and `<ion-pane>` by implementing `<ion-content scroll="false">` and `<ion-pane scroll="false">`, respectively. The text now loads perfectly as it should.